# Windows duplicating printer with custom name

Tags: windows, powershell, printing

My organization uses a piece of software that has a printer name hard-coded into it `PRN1`.

Users are spread out through multiple locations; so it is impossible to just rename a single printer. Our networked printers are mapped by computer location via a login script; and some computers have locally attached printers.

The current proposed solution is to remote into each computer with the user logged in; re-map the users default printer; and manually rename it (Right click->Printer Prop...).

I'm trying to avoid this as we do not use roaming profiles and some users do move from location to location; and the users wouldn't understand why it suddenly isn't working.

Ideally I'd like to create a script that will automatically duplicate the users default printer; and name it `PRN1`.

```
$AllPrinters = gwmi win32_printer
$DefaultPrinter = $AllPrinters | where {$_.Default -eq $true}
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n $DefaultPrinter.SystemName + "\" + $DefaultPrinter.ShareName /z /b"PRN1"
```

Above is what I currently have; I know I'm not using the `rundll32` command properly as the printer isn't being duplicated with the new name.

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use that rundll32 command here and there but never have solid luck with it.

You could do something like this by using wmi entirely. You may want to wrap a try catch around a large chunk of this to suppress errors and log output if users do end up having issues.

```
$Name = "PRN"

$AllPrinters = gwmi win32_printer
$DefaultPrinter = $AllPrinters | where {$_.Default -eq $true}

    $objHelper = [WMICLASS]"\\localhost\root\cimv2:Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper"
    $print = [WMICLASS]"\\localhost\root\cimv2:Win32_Printer"
    $print.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true
        $newprinter = $print.createInstance() 
            $newprinter.drivername = $DefaultPrinter.DriverName
            $newprinter.PortName = $DefaultPrinter.PortName
            $newprinter.Shared = $false
            $newprinter.Location = $DefaultPrinter.Location
            $newprinter.Comment = $DefaultPrinter.Comment
            $newprinter.DeviceID = $Name
            $newprinter.PrintProcessor = $DefaultPrinter.PrintProcessor
            $newprinter.PrintJobDataType = $DefaultPrinter.DataType
            $newprinter.RawOnly = $DefaultPrinter.RawOnly 

        $result = $newprinter.Put()
```

Comment: 100% what I was looking for; Thank you so much!

Putting this into a login script will be so much easier than going to every user.